What three letter word fits here?
Here is some enigmatic text from 1 to 10 (sort of).
What three letters fit in the missing places (marked by ?), which anagram to a three letter word? (don't need the actual positions, just the final word and an explanation)
1. S?T?TFS
II. WHEN O?IE
V. 1 RUNG XV
EE HERE
10.


The three-letter words that fits here is...

 FIT, the only common anagram of the letters F, I and T.

Because this 'enigmatic text from 1 to 10 (sort of)' is - quite literally -

 ...the numbers from 1 to 10, but spelled out vertically, selecting one letter per line, sans three letters marked as question marks.

 Oddly (to some who have been led up the garden path, perhaps), it is nothing at all to do with the red herring 'days of the week' theme suggested in the first line ("S?T?TFS" would be the first letters of the days of the week, Sunday through Saturday, missing 'M' for Monday and 'W' for Wednesday) - this is just a convenient ruse intended to lead us astray!

In order for this to work, one minor (but legal) alteration needs to be made to the given text...

 All appearance of digits in the passage must be spelled out in letters, so '1' should be 'ONE' and '10' should be 'TEN'. Removing spaces and unnecessary punctuation, this results in the puzzle text taking the form:

 ONES?T?TFS
 IIWHENO?IE
 VONERUNGXV
 EEHERE
 TEN

 Note that the top three rows now all comprise precisely ten characters, which is exactly what we'd hope to see given that the names of all the numbers 1-10 are each at least 3 letters long...

Let's reorder the letters in each line to show this more clearly and succinctly:

 
 OTTF?SSEN?
 NWHOIIEI?E
 EORUVXVGNN
   ERE EHE
   E   NT


 Read downwards!

This gives our three question marks as:

 F and T in the top row (to complete the spellings of 'FIVE' and 'TEN'), and I in the second (for 'NINE'). Together, these anagram to FIT, a fitting word for a puzzle which asks us "What three letter word fits here?"!


I'm kinda impressed by the fact that the ends of the columns happen to be an anagram for one of the columns
